# How to create a datagrid with custom fields

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am very new to asp.net...
I have to create a page which looks like this.

Name:[text field],  Start_date[Datapicker], End_date[Date Picket]

Where in, the above row can be repeated based on start_date and end_date the user select. For Example if user fill date as:
Name: **XYZ** start_date:**1/2/2011** End_Date: **6/6/2011**

Then we need to populate one more similar row with same fields as above, until start and end covers one complete year.

Initially single row will be there, but finally its ends up all follows:

EX1: *Name: XXX Start_Date:**1/12011** End_DAte: **6/6/2011**
       Name: YYY start_Date:**7/6/2011** End_Date: **31/12/2011***

EX2: Name: XXX Start_Date:**1/12011** End_DAte: **31/12/2011**

Comment: you are looking for a way to add new rows to datagrid with textbox and calendar controls in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a DataGrid, it sounds like a Repeater control might work better for what you are looking to accomplish.